# Instancing Objects - New (Kinda) Feature?

Tags: objects, instances

Ok so I’ve been playing around with instancing and duplicating linked. Both are very cool.

It seems that duplicating linked has most of the performance of instancing, but with the added flexibility of being able to change object properties, while using the same mesh. Aka the verts / faces / memory of the scene stay consistent regardless of how many you have in the scene.

However, it’s always confused me as to how you can instance a collection, instance a child object on a parent’s vertices and faces, but you can’t just instance an object by itself. For cases where you want everything to be replicated, including the settings of the object, a pure instance on an object level would be very nice, without having to add it to a collection first. The mechanism seems to be there in terms of already being able to instance children on the parents vertexes / faces.

Would you all find that a useful feature?
Can you already do this, and I’m just not seeing it?

[image]

Comment: Instancing objects works with mesh objects, not empties. You have to make the instanced mesh a child of the instancer. Then choose whether you want to instance on faces or vertices. The most simple setup is to instance an object on a parent instancer with a single vertex at 0, 0, 0, giving the same functionality as an instanced collection, but you can only do it once since an object can only have one parent. But you can duplicate the vertex in edit mode to instance several copies of the child object.

Comment: I don't see what would be the advantage of such a thing at first glance, to be honest. Isn't Alt+D duplicating linked already that (and more, as you say)?

Comment: @Gorgious I think you misunderstood my question. What I was asking is whether having an option on empties to instance objects (that aren't their children) like you can collections, would be useful. I already know about instancing children on parent vertices and faces. It's useful for having those objects form the shape of the parent, but gets pretty convoluted if you want to just instance those objects around and have to add more vertices around. Hence the question of adding that as an option to the empty instance property, to instance objects.

Comment: @Kuboå I think the benefit of this option would be that instances instance the object data as well, not just the mesh data. So having a 1000 instances of one object vs 1000 duplicated linked objects means you only have one object, and all of the settings on that object the its instances are the same, since it's an instance, not a duplicated object with a linked mesh. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you explored Geometry Nodes ? An instance on points on a single vertex should achieve what you're after

Comment: @Lichen Yeah it does make some sense, and perhaps it is surprising that it didn't come first—what did they do before Collections were a thing? But I guess simply putting the object in a collection is so easy (and also gives you an option of adding more objects to the instances down the line) that it's not exactly a "missing" feature that's holding the user back, so while I wouldn't mind having the option, I wouldn't bother trying to convince the devs either.

Comment: @Gorgious I have indeed! They're very cool. This question is more directed at being able to create object instances quickly and using them in specific locations in a scene. I could use geo nodes for it but it would require more setup and time than justing being able to click select an object and then from the add menu "Create Object Instance" and move it where desired. Thanks though!

Comment: @Kuboå For sure! That was my thinking. I would have thought that object instancing would have come before collection instancing. Especially with the fact that you cant move objects in the collection that is instanced without affecting the placement of the objects in the instanced collection (least as far as I can tell), since collections are more like boundless layers than they are localized to the objects inside them. Hence why they don't have transforms, origins etc. Which makes sense given their nature.

Comment: @Kuboå Which is where object instances would be great, since the instance could be based on the object origin. Which would allow you to move the object that the instance is based on, without having that move the instance.

I'm going to see if I can figure out how to add that feature since it would be super useful for me. In the meantime duplicate linked is fine, just not ideal for some cases.

Comment: AFAICT the feature that resembles the most what you are looking for is the library override workflow, but it requires linking objects from other files, as you can't override an object that's inside the current file. Weird limitation but I think improvements are in the works.